# I need a more specific Powershell command to isolate Active Directory names, usernames, and last login date from users on a domain

Tags: powershell, cmd, scripting, active-directory, windows-7

I'm an IT intern tasked with performing an audit of users on our domain and I'm having some trouble finding the info I need without all of the extra stuff. Is there a way to pull all of this info in one command? If not, can you recommend commands to pull users, usernames, and login info separately in a manner that I can copy-paste in the format I need?

I previously used `get-adgroup -filter *` and wrote to a file. Are there some options I can add for this filter? I also used a script to get all users, and all groups and their user permissions on separate occasions.

Comment: What exactly is "all of this info"? What is "login info"? We need to know what you're having trouble with if we are to help you :)

Comment: there is a big, large, huge, gigantic pile of data per object ... [*grin*] ... so most of the AD cmdlets return only a basic set _unless_ you ask for more. take a look at the `-Properties` parameter of the AD cmdlets  for more info. for a list of default & "all the rest" properties for a user object, lookee ... >>> Active Directory: Get-ADUser Default and Extended Properties - TechNet Articles - United States (English) - TechNet Wiki — https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12037.active-directory-get-aduser-default-and-extended-properties.aspx <<<

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -like '*Accounting*'" | 
  Get-ADGroupMember | 
  Select-Object name, SamAccountName
```

Or if you need more fields from the user object, then try something like:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -like '*Accounting*'" | 
  Get-ADGroupMember | 
  Get-ADUser -Properties Enabled | 
  Select-Object Name, SamAccountName, UserPrincipalName, Enabled
```

You'll probably want to export to a spreadsheet, so use `Export-Csv` for that.